# Partial-mocking considered bad practice? (Mockito)

Tags: mockito, partial-mocks

I'm unit-testing a business object using Mockito. The business object uses a DAO which normally gets data from a DB. To test the business object, I realized that it was easier to use a separate in-memory DAO (which keeps data in a HashMap) than to write all the

```
when(...).thenReturn(...)
```

statements. To create such a DAO, I started by partial-mocking my DAO interface like so:

```
when(daoMock.getById(anyInt())).then(new Answer() {
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        int id = (Integer) invocation.getArguments()[0];
        return map.get(id);
    }
});
```

but it occurred to me that it was easier to just implement a whole new DAO implementation myself (using in-memory HashMap) without even using Mockito (no need to get arguments out of that InvocationOnMock object) and make the tested business object use this new DAO.

Additionally, I've read that partial-mocking was considered bad practice. My question is: is what I'm doing a bad practice in my case? What are the downsides? To me this seems OK and I'm wondering what the potential problems could be.

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering why you need your fake DAO to be backed by a `HashMap`.  I'm wondering whether your tests are too complex.  I'm a big fan of having very simple test methods that each test one aspect of your SUT's behaviour.  In principle, this is "one assertion per test", although sometimes I end up with a small handful of actual `assert` or `verify` lines, for example, if I'm asserting the correctness of a complex object.  Please read http://blog.astrumfutura.com/2009/02/unit-testing-one-test-one-assertion-why-it-works/ or http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/06/testing-one-assertion-per-test.html to learn more about this principle.

So for each test method, you shouldn't be using your fake DAO over and over.  Probably just once, or twice at the very most.  Therefore, having a big `HashMap` full of data would seem to me to be EITHER redundant, OR an indication that your test is doing WAY more than it should.  For each test method, you should really only need one or two items of data.  If you set these up using a Mockito mock of your DAO interface, and put your `when ... thenReturn` in the test method itself, each test will be simple and readable, because the data that the particular test uses will be immediately visible.

You may also want to read up on the "arrange, act, assert" pattern, (http://www.arrangeactassert.com/why-and-what-is-arrange-act-assert/ and http://www.telerik.com/help/justmock/basic-usage-arrange-act-assert.html) and be careful about implementing this pattern INSIDE each test method, rather than having different parts of it scattered across your test class.

Without seeing more of your actual test code, it's difficult to know what other advice to give you.  Mockito is supposed to make mocking easier, not harder; so if you've got a test where that's not happening for you, then it's certainly worth asking whether you're doing something non-standard.  What you're doing is not "partial mocking", but it certainly seems like a bit of a testing smell to me.  Not least because it couples lots of your test methods together - ask yourself what would happen if you had to change some of the data in the `HashMap`.

You may find https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/158397/do-large-test-methods-indicate-a-code-smell useful too.

Answer (score 1):

When testing my classes, I often use a combination of Mockito-made mocks and also fakes, which are very much what you are describing. In your situation I agree that a fake implementation sounds better.

There's nothing particularly wrong with partial mocks, but it makes it a little harder to determine when you're calling the real object and when you're calling your mocked method--especially because Mockito silently fails to mock final methods. Innocent-looking changes to the original class may change the implementation of the partial mock, causing your test to stop working.

If you have the flexibility, I recommend extracting an interface that exposes the method you need to call, which will make it easier whether you choose a mock or a fake.

To write a fake, implement that small interface without Mockito using a simple class (nested in your test, if you'd like). This will make it very easy to see what is happening; the downside is that if you write a very complicated Fake you may find you need to test the Fake too. If you have a lot of tests that could make use of a good Fake implementation, this may be worth the extra code.

I highly recommend ["Mocks aren't Stubs"](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html), an article by Martin Fowler (famous for his book *Refactoring*). He goes over the names of different types of test doubles, and the differences between them.

Comment: Thanks. This has been useful advice to me :) I will read the article and wait a little for other answers before I mark this as the accepted one.